# How to correctly add an existing ssh key for Bitbucket

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket, ssh-keys

I have a ssh key on Bitbucket, which I used on the previous computer, how do I bind the same key to a new computer, so as not to create a new one. There are currently no id_rsa and id_rsa.pub files in the ./ssh folder. I need to create these folders first, and then copy the key there? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

1) Create the .ssh directory

```
mkdir $HOME/.ssh
```

2) Set the directory permission

```
chmod 700 $HOME/.ssh
```

3) Copy the id_rsa and id_rsa.pub files to the .ssh directory

```
cp PATH/id_rsa $HOME/.ssh
cp PATH/id_rsa.pub $HOME/.ssh
```

Or from another computer

```
scp USER@COMPUTER:PATH/id_rsa $HOME/.ssh
scp USER@COMPUTER:PATH/id_rsa.pub $HOME/.ssh
```

4) Be sure that the id_rsa files has the correct permission

```
chmod 600 $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa
chmod 644 $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I would like to clarify how to correctly copy the files id_rsa.pub and id_rsa from another computer? Sorry for the stupid question